# How should be my root folder structure?

Tags: wordpress, root

I would like to show inside my own website, other website projects to my clients. For example:

www.mywebsite.com/clients/obama-client/index-obama.php

However, the website for my client is in this case a Wordpress site, so, inside my own root folders I have a file for all the wordpress data as this:

www.mywebsite.com/blog/ ALL THE FILES

This blog folder was created because I wanted to some day have my own blog inside my website, however I am trying to use this same files to operate the worpress sites of my clients, just to show them how are the projects because later, they will have their own servers to just upload all the project from my site to theirs.

Unfortunately, now when I tried to install a new "theme" (a full worpress site) using my own wp-admin area, I have this message: "no style.css found inside the .zip".

So I think this might be because of my own style.css ? How can I solve this ? How can my root folder should be ?

many tks!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you need to activate 'Multisite': http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

Also this is a Wordpress question and not really a programming question.